# Running a excel macro script on all files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, csv

before people say this question has been asked before, trust me I have read most entries but I just can't get my head around it. I have a fold of about 550 CSV files, each about 25mb. I'm trying to automatically remove the unnecessary columns to bring the file size down to 2mb, so that then I can analyse them with another language ( that I'm more comfortable with )

I found this code on the net :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_First_Last_Columns_From_CSV_Files()

    Dim source_folder_name As String
    source_folder_name = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop\" 'change the path to the source folder accordingly

    If Right(source_folder_name, 1) <> "\" Then
        source_folder_name = source_folder_name & "\"
    End If

    If Len(source_folder_name) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path to the source folder is invalid!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Path"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim columns_to_delete As Variant
    columns_to_delete = Array("First", "Last") 'change and/or add column headers as desired

    Dim current_filename As String
    current_filename = Dir(source_folder_name & "*.csv", vbNormal)

    Dim file_count As Long
    While Len(current_filename) > 0
        file_count = file_count + 1
        Delete_Columns_from_CSV_File source_folder_name & current_filename, columns_to_delete
        current_filename = Dir
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Number of files processed: " & file_count, vbInformation, "Files Processed"

End Sub

Private Sub Delete_Columns_from_CSV_File(ByVal source_filename As String, ByVal columns_to_delete As Variant)

    Dim source_workbook As Workbook
    Set source_workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=source_filename)

    Dim source_worksheet As Worksheet
    Set source_worksheet = source_workbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim column_found As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(columns_to_delete) To UBound(columns_to_delete)
        Set column_found = source_worksheet.Rows(1).Find(what:=columns_to_delete(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not column_found Is Nothing Then
            column_found.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    source_workbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

I paste this code through visual basic part of EXCEL to the current workbook, but it only runs the script on the current file and not the rest of the folder. How do I fix it so it runs on all files ?

Comment: Your code processes every file in a folder for me.  Let us try to diagnose your problem. 
 Click on the statement `current_filename = Dir` and then click F9.  The statement will be coloured brown.  Now run your code.  Execution will stop on the brown statement.  If you hover over data names, their value will be displayed.  Look at `current_filename`.  Have the unwanted columns been deleted from that file?  Click F8 which will execute one statement.   Has `current_filename` changed value?  You should also investigate `Delete_Columns_from_CSV_File`.  Is it finding the columns to be deleted?

Comment: `After column_found.EntireColumn.Delete` add `Else` `Debug.Print "Column " & columns_to_delete(i) & " of file " & source_filename & " not found"`

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thanks for the reply. When I run the macro on one file it does the job, but I have to open files one by one to get it done. Where am I supposed to run the script ? What I've done so far is I opened one of the files in the target folder and went to visual basic, right click on the workbook ==> insert module and ran the code from there

Comment: That is not necessary.  Create a macro-enabled workbook.  (Do you know how? I will add an explanation if necessary.)  Place your code in a module within that workbook.  Run the code. The code will search `source_folder_name` for every CSV file, open each CSV file in turn and delete the unwanted columns.